# css "first-child" with li tag

Tags: html, css

```
   <ul>
        <li class="bla">aaa</li>
        <li class="my_li">sss</li>
        <li class="my_li">ddd</li>
        <li class="my_li">fff</li>
    </ul>
```

css:

```
    .my_li:first-child{
            color: #090;
    }
```

this not working, if make for first li tag class not "bla", but "my_li", alreday li element set green color. Someone tell please, why this happened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first element that is a member of the class "my_li" is the second child of its parent.

`:first-child` selects elements that are the first child of their parent.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this selector:

```
.my_li:nth-child(2) { ... }
```

(if I'm understanding your question currently and you want the 2nd <li> to have this style)

Comment: This is very useful answer, thaks for this

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because that selector means you're choosing an element with class my_li which is the first child of its parent, that is not present in your html.

Try

```
<ul>
    <li class="my_li">aaa</li>
    <li class="my_li">sss</li>
    <li class="my_li">ddd</li>
    <li class="my_li">fff</li>
</ul>
```

Then your rule will apply to aaa.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to change the class for the first element, use :

```
ul li:first-child{
            color: #090;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12319879/1164726) said, `:first-child` referes to the first element of its parent.

If you want to target the first element of your example list, do this:

```
ul li:first-child {
   color: #090;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to add a second class to your `li` element

CSS:

```
.first_li{ color:#090; }

<ul>
  <li class="bla">aaa</li>
  <li class="my_li first_li">sss</li>
  <li class="my_li">ddd</li>
  <li class="my_li">fff</li>
</ul>
```

you could solve your problem with the `:nth-child(n)` selector, but that means you need to know exactly in which order is the `li` element inside its parent `ul` (in this case 2nd child) and if you insert more elements this will fail.

```
css: .my_li:nth-child(2){ color: #090;}
```